# UITableView: can I delete multiple rows?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I want to delete multiple rows from a table view, based on the user's selection. Obviously I can't use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method because it will be called for every row selected. I want to allow the user to select multiple rows for deletion and then delete them in one go. Is it possible?

If yes, then how to go about it? Also, I am using a single-view-based project and I want the header of the table view changed to "Delete", on the same view, when the user wants to delete the rows from the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something this way:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView
      didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

[theTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[theTableView indexPathForSelectedRow] animated:NO];
UITableViewCell *cell = [theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:newIndexPath];
if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [selectedCellsMutableArray addObject:newIndexPath];
} else if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [selectedCellsMutableArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:newIndexPath];
}
```

}

When user press **Delete Selected** button - just invoke something like

```
// change your model here and then:
[yourView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:selectedCellsMutableArray
                withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
```

Answer (score 0):

A late reply, but another way to handle this (if you are targeting iOS 5) is to toggle editing mode and use the built-in multiple cell selection. Easiest way to do this is to put this in viewDidLoad...

```
// add edit button to navigation bar, which auto toggles editing mode
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
// allows user to select multiple cells while in editing mode
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
```

[See documentation for more details](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html)